# Scroll fixed div to certain point

Tags: jquery

I have seen a few examples of these, but mine is a little different and can't figure this out.

I'm using a piece of jQuery found on these forums, to scroll a fixed div to certain point then stopping, using 'scrollTop'.

```
var windw = this;

$.fn.followTo = function ( pos ) {
    var $this = this,
        $window = $(windw);

    $window.scroll(function(e){
        if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
            $this.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: pos
            });
        } else {
            $this.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: 40
            });
        }
    });
};

$('#scrollto-menu-nav').followTo(250);
```

However, I need it to stop scrolling when it reaches a height from the **bottom** not from the **top**. Any ideas?

Thanks,
R

Comment: You could try to calculate the total height of the item you want it to stop from the bottom of, then deduct from that a number to get to where you want it to stop. For example 150 - 100 would give a position value of 50.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<img src=//ph.artsinn.de alt>
<div>
    <p>A short line of text, for better interpretation.</p>
    <p>Followed by another line, filled with letter and words</p> 
</div>

<img src=//ph.artsinn.de/240x160/666?text=scroll%20down alt id=obj>

<img src=//ph.artsinn.de alt>
<img src=//ph.artsinn.de alt>
<img src=//ph.artsinn.de alt class=end>

<div>
    <p>A short line of text, for better interpretation.</p>
    <p>Followed by another line, filled with letter and words</p> 
</div>

<img src=//ph.artsinn.de alt>
<img src=//ph.artsinn.de alt>
<img src=//ph.artsinn.de alt>
<img src=//ph.artsinn.de alt>​
```

**CSS**

```
/* not needed */
html,body{height:200%}
img {display:block}​
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    var $window = $(window),
        $sidebar = $("#obj"),
        sidebarTop = $sidebar.position().top,
        sidebarHeight = $sidebar.height(),
        $footer = $(".end"),
        footerTop = $footer.position().top;

    $sidebar.css('position', 'fixed');
    $window.scroll(function(e) {
        scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
        topPosition = Math.max(0, sidebarTop - scrollTop);
        topPosition = Math.min(topPosition, (footerTop - scrollTop) - sidebarHeight);
        $sidebar.css('top', topPosition);
    });
});​
```

And, again, as [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/E6xEe/).